# OpenVPN Access Server is dangerously visible to everybody

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, windows-server-2016

I have an OpenVPN Access Server running on Hyper-V on a Windows Server with a static IP. It's purpose is to grant remote access to my network.

Now the Access Server is visible and accessible for anybody in the Internet, as long as they have the password and the IP, which makes it dangerously hackable.

Is there a way to restrict access from the Internet?
Maybe by requiring a certificate that can only be installed when I'm in the local network?

I don't want people to be able to download the certificate remotely. And also to restrict access to the control panel from outside the local network.

Best would be if no one could see that there even is a server if they unknowingly enter the IP.

Would be great if someone can hint me in the right direction. Thank you!

Comment: Are you talking about restricting the VPN service or the control panel, or both?

Comment: I'm talking about both. I don't want useres to be able to download the certificate remotely. And also to restrict access to the control panel from outside the local network.

Comment: Okay, so if access to the VPN service is restricted, how are your users going to connect to the VPN when they go outside the "range"? Doesn't that literally defeat the whole point of a VPN service?

Comment: Why did you ask that question then?

Here is what I want:

I want the users to have and be able to download their certificate only on the local Network.

I want only users with the certificate to be able to connect to the vpn service remotely.

I want no one to be able to download the certificate remotely or access the control panel.

Clear enough?

Help is appreciated